# Find the Fourier coefficient for the function $f(t)=t^3-2t$

Tags: fourier-series

I'm trying to find the $a_5$ Fourier coefficient for

$f(t)=t^3-2t$ from $-π<t<π$

I think I'm supposed to get $a_5=0.32$.  However, I don't know how to get there.  If that is the right answer, how do I get to there?  If that's not right, how do I do this problem to get to the right answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the formulas for the coefficients?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (t^3 - 2t)\cos (5t)\,dt$$

Comment: @DanielFischer You got zero.

Comment: @FelixMarin Explain? I don't understand. (internet meme?)

Comment: @DanielFischer The integrand is odd.

Comment: @FelixMarin Oh, the value. Yes, all the $a_n$ are.

Answer (score 0):

You should have clarified what $a_5$ means. It could be the coefficient of $\cos 5t $ in one book, and the coefficient of $\sin 5t$ in another. If it's the former, the correct answer is $0$. Indeed, $t^3-2t$ is an odd function, and its Fourier series has sines only, no cosines. If it's the coefficient of $\sin 5t$, the value is 
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} (t^3-2t)\sin 5t\,dt =\frac{2}{125}(25\pi^2-56)\approx 3
$$